# SEAT Alhambra (2014) spare wheel

Tags: wheels, seat, spare-tire

I have a SEAT Alhambra (2014) which does not come with a spare wheel.  I want to buy a cheap spare wheel (2nd hand maybe), that I can keep in my garage for emergencies but I have no clue about these things. All I know its a bigger wheel than by Skoda, can I find what my size of wheel is and get a generic spare wheel for it? or can I use a same size wheel from a different brand car (2nd hand)?  I think my wheel is 16 inch, will any 16 inch wheel work on it?
I Tried googling this but can't straight answer ( most result are websites selling new wheels)

If it makes any difference, it a UK car

Comment: Different vehicles have different number of fixing studs. My Ford has 4, my Skoda has 5. Have a look on a website, for example [Tyres Outlet UK](https://www.tyres-outlet.co.uk/Steel-Rims.html) sells steel and alloy **rims** and has options to select the model of your car. Apart from that, go to a breaker's yard and find the right car.

Comment: In addition to making sure the new spare will bolt correctly to your car's hubs (number of studs, size of the circle of studs, wheel offset), make sure the spare tire well in your car is big enough to accommodate the wheel/tire combo you choose; some cars' wells are big enough only for compact, limited-use spares.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Just wanted to understand it a bit more before I to the breaker yard.  The seat alhambra does not have a tire well ( or come with a jack or tyre wrench), so that's why i'm keeping it in the garage (and so the size does not matter as long as it works)